# AS3 CS6 Remove movieclip from array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I'm working on a project for college. I'm making a Third Person Top Down shooter game, I have almost finished but stuck on one main part of the game, getting the enemy movieclip to be removed from the stage when it's hit by a bullet movieclip.

I've managed to get the bullet to be removed from the stage when it hits the enemy and tried copying the code and manipulating it accordingly to remove the enemy also but it doesn't seem to want to work, it throws out 3 errors:

`Enemy.as, Line 14  1120: Access of undefined property bulletList.`

```
bullets = bulletList;
```

---

`Enemy.as, Line 44  1120: Access of undefined property stageRef.`

```
if (stageRef.contains(this))
```

---

`Enemy.as, Line 45  1120: Access of undefined property stageRef.`

```
stageRef.removeChild(this);
```

---

All the AS3 source files can be downloaded for viewing [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byn882kLw50gbjdGaTVYYmFCYjg/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: No one is going to dig through your code - please add the relevant lines to your question.

Comment: I've added the specific lines that's causing the errors under the error code itself.

Comment: it would be most helpful to see these lines in context with the rest of the code. I clicked the link but nothing was there... try adding `_root.` in front of the variables and see if that assists. `if (_root.stageRef.contains(this))` and `_root.stageRef.removeChild(this);`

Comment: @Phlume `_root` is an ActionScript 2 property, it does not exist in AS3.

Comment: ah shoot... yup. loose the underscore... `(root.stageRef.contains(this))` and `root.stageRef.removeChild(this);`

Comment: @Phlume, sorry I forgot to make the download public. Also adding `root` hasn't made any difference, it's still throwing up the same errors. Did I mention that the enemies are in an array? I think telling you that might help.

Comment: Would it be better if I just paste my code here? Well, in my question? I just thought putting a download link for them would be better so my question was readable and it didn't make it a mile of scrolling down the page.

Comment: And sorry @MartyWallace, I wasn't expecting anyone to 'dig' through my code, I just thought it would be easier to see what the statements are referring to and what functions it was calling because my if statement for `hitTestObject(this)` calls a function called `removeSelf` which is where the last two errors are.

Comment: another suggestion is rather than adding root add MovieClip(root) in front of those variables.

Comment: Thanks thats gotten rid of the last two errors, it's just the one on line 14 now thats throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly defines that the variable bulletList and stageRef do not exist or are not reachable at this point in the code. How about checking if you have created these variables before trying to access them.

It also would be helpful if you past your Enemy.as (or at least the relevant method where the error occurs).